# Queueable DML capability

Tags: queueable-interface, queueable-apex

When using Queueable class for DML operation, what are the limits impose? Is it 10,000 dml rows and 50,000 rows retrieved from SOQL?

In fact i was trying to implement the queuable interface in a trigger, so as that, when i run into too many dml rows, i can complete the dml using a queueable class, as i assume that if it is asynchronous, then it is not the same transaction, thus the number of dml operations is reset. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct, performing your DML operations inside a Queueable execution is a separate transaction so you will have a fresh set of governor limits.

Comment: I will try it, and test this assumption. Thanks for the answer, this give me a boost to start implementing. But any idea on SOQL and DML limits for queueable????

Comment: SOQL & DML limits no different than for any other Asynch APEX transaction. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#asyncExecutionLimit for applicable limits.